# Generation Error for Source Class

Tags: magento2.3, setup-di-compile, magento2.3.1

I'm trying to compile etc. after recently upgrading to Magento 2.3.1.

I use this command:

```
$ php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

which returns this error:

> Source class "\Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductField" for "Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper" generation does not exist.

But I don't get why it's not being generated, here are my file permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 15 dev-admin devs          4096 Apr 10 16:22 ./
drwxrwxr-x  6 dev-admin devs            65 Apr 10 16:08 ../
drwxrwxr-x  5 dev-admin devs           122 Apr 10 16:22 app/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin      234 Apr 10 16:22 auth.json.sample*
drwxrwxr-x  2 dev-admin devs            38 Apr 10 16:22 bin/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin   434981 Apr 10 16:22 CHANGELOG.md*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin     2152 Apr 10 16:15 composer.json*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin devs        636665 Apr 10 16:22 composer.lock*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin      650 Apr 10 16:22 COPYING.txt*
drwxrwxr-x  5 dev-admin devs            63 Apr 10 16:22 dev/
drwxrwxrwx  3 dev-admin dev-admin       35 Apr 10 16:47 generated/
drwxrwxr-x  3 dev-admin dev-admin      151 Apr 10 16:22 .github/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin devs          1437 Jun 25  2018 .gitignore*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin    12076 Apr 10 16:22 .htaccess*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin     1370 Apr 10 16:22 index.php*
drwxrwxr-x  4 dev-admin devs            50 Apr 10 16:22 lib/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin    10376 Apr 10 16:22 LICENSE_AFL.txt*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin    10364 Apr 10 16:22 LICENSE.txt*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin     1654 Apr 10 16:22 .php_cs.dist*
drwxrwxr-x  2 dev-admin dev-admin       58 Apr 10 16:22 phpserver/
drwxrwxrwx  6 dev-admin devs           201 Apr 10 16:22 pub/
drwxrwxr-x  7 dev-admin dev-admin      115 Apr 10 16:22 setup/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin     2095 Apr 10 16:22 .travis.yml*
drwxrwxr-x  7 dev-admin dev-admin      191 Apr 10 16:03 update/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dev-admin dev-admin      101 Apr 10 16:22 .user.ini*
drwxrwxrwx 10 dev-admin devs         237 Apr 10 16:47 var/
drwxrwxr-x 62 dev-admin devs          4096 Apr 10 16:22 vendor/
```

so `generated/` has full permissions... how do I go about debugging this and actually getting this to generate so I can actually finish my upgrade?

Comment: try run upgrade then compile or upgrade then indexer then compile

Comment: @magefms I upgrade before this ^^ that gets through without a hitch

Comment: @magefms will try index though

Comment: alright you can check

Comment: @magefms tried with `indexer:reindex` to no avail :/

Comment: still the same error?

Comment: @magefms yeah :/

Comment: maybe try to remove first the generated folder and run compile again

Comment: @magefms i did do that beforehand.. but I guess trying again can't hurt, weirdly the site runs ok (with a few minor bugs) :S

Comment: that's kind of weird. at least now it works :)

Comment: @magefms yeah :S guess I'll close the q for time being haha